# Undefined method 'queryActivos'.The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need get a entity from a entityRepository.
But in my formType, when i call my function queryActivos, i get the next error:

Undefined method 'queryActivos'.The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

This is my field in formtype:

```
->add('articulosDefectuosos','entity', array(
                'empty_value' => 'SELECCIONE ARTICULO DEFECTUOSO',
                'class'     => 'VentasAlmacenBundle:ArticuloDefectuoso',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->queryActivos();
                },
                'attr'  =>  array(
                    'class' => "browser-default"
                )
            ))
```

This is the entity :

```
/**
 * DevolucionProveedor
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CeiferIT\VentasAlmacenBundle\Entity\DevolucionProveedorRepository")
 */
class DevolucionProveedor
{
```

And this my repository:

```
class DevolucionProveedorRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function queryActivos()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('af')
            ->where('af.activo = :activo')
            ->setParameter('activo', true);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be in the VentasAlmacenBundle:ArticuloDefectuoso repository

Comment: Oh, yes... Today I am satured sorry and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class DevolucionProveedorRepository extends EntityRepository
```

{

```
public function findByqueryActivos($yourVariable)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('af')
        ->where('af.activo = :activo')
        ->setParameter('activo', true);
    return $query;
}
```

}